# How to Install (nic) drivers on TrueNAS

Tags: freebsd, nic, truenas, gigabit-ethernet

How can one update a network card driver on TrueNAS 12.0?

My nic is on the motherboard directly it's a Intel Motherboard DH55HC, the NIC is 82578DC gigabit enabled.

I've found the driver directly at Intel's site for FreeBSD; https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/17509/Intel-Network-Adapter-Gigabit-Base-Driver-for-FreeBSD-

Not sure how to install it? I've listed below the reason I'm trying to do this.

---

I'm not getting gigabit link speed on my trueNAS box. I've tested the cables, changed the settings in TrueNAS shell via: `ifconfig <interface-name> <ip_address> media 1000baseTX mediaopt full-duplex`
but doing so just kills the connection & the machine is no longer pingable from the network nor does it appear in the devices list of my router.

The router is gigabit capable: `Netgear R6700v2` with other machines connected at gigabit speeds.

The cables are brand new cat6 confirmed & I've crimped both ends twice to ensure they are correctly wired to the RJ45 connector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installation instructions are in the [README](https://downloadmirror.intel.com/17509/eng/README.txt) on the site you linked to.

In fact, FreeBSD has built in support for this driver. See `man igb(4)` and how to enable it.

> NAME
> igb -- Intel(R) PRO/1000 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet adapter driver
>
> SYNOPSIS
> To   compile this driver into the kernel, place the following line in your
> kernel configuration file:
>
> ```
>  device igb
>
>  Alternatively, to load the   driver as a module at boot time, place the
>  following line in loader.conf(5):
>
>  if_igb_load="YES"
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
> The igb driver provides support for PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet adapters
> based on **the Intel 82575 and 82576 Ethernet controller chips**.  The   driver
> supports Transmit/Receive checksum   offload and Jumbo Frames.  Furthermore
> it   supports TCP segmentation offload (TSO) on all adapters.

Comment: Hi Rob, Searching for `man igb(4)` I found this page https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=igb&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD+7.2-RELEASE but when setting the media type to `1000baseTX` the connection drops. What do you mean by enable it??

Comment: @UserSN From the man page: "to load the driver as a module at boot time, place the following line in loader.conf(5): if_igb_load="YES"" and you need to reboot.

Comment: my nic is EM not IGB though, does that make any difference? I was reading here: https://www.reddit.com/r/freebsd/comments/alpt9j/freebsd_112_to_120_upgrade_igb_moved_to_em/

Comment: @UserSN My answer is about installing the drivers you pointed to.  I don't have more info beyond that at the moment.

Comment: understood, I've accepted the answer and will create a new question for the underlying problem. Thank you